# Error Returned from a Select/Inner Join Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to run the following statement, an error message is returned:
Server: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'vendortofaultypeitemsmap'.

SQL Help indicates this message appears when "an object that does not exist is referenced".  This table does exist and returns values if I run *select * from vendortofaulttypeitemsmap*.  Can someone help me pinpoint what is wrong with the statement below that is causing the error message?  Thanks in advance.

```
select 
    vendortofaulttypeitemsmap.vendorid, 
    vendortofaulttypeitemsmap.faultypeitemguid,
    guid_faulttypeitems.faulttypeitemname,
    vendortoworkactionmap.workactionitemguid, 
    guid_workactionitem.workactionitemname
from vendortofaultypeitemsmap
    inner join guid_faulttypeitems on
    vendortofaulttypeitemsmap.faultypeitemguid=
        guid_faulttypeitems.faultypeitemguid
    inner join guid_workactionitem on
    vendortoworkactionmap.workactionitemguid=   
        guid_workactionitem.workactionitemguid
where vendortofaulttypeitemsmap.vendorid=45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. It is either vendortofaultypeitemsmap or vendortofaulttypeitemsmap.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I must have looked at it 20 times and never saw the typo.

Comment: @Erin - no problem, an extra pair of eyes is always good.

Answer (score 3):

You missed a 't' vendortofaultTypeitemsmap.

Answer (score 2):

Writing those table names out every time makes it easy to make typos. Use table aliases to simplify the whole thing, and change it to:

```
select v.VendorID, v.FaultTypeItemGUID, f.FaultTypeItemName, 
       v.WorkActionItemGUID, w.WorkActionItemName 
from VendorToFaultTypeItemsMap v
inner join GUID_FaultTypeItems f on v.FaultTypeItemGUID = g.FaultTypeItemGUID 
inner join GUID_WorkActionItem w on v.WorkActionItemGUID = w.WorkActionItemGUID
where v.VendorID = 45
```

With long names like that, using mixed case can also help you spot problems easier (assuming your database isn't set to case-sensitive).